# Windows 10 import multiples xml via CMD

Tags: windows-10, export, import, wifi-transfer

My geal is transfer more then 100+ wifi xml files to another computer. Is there any way how to do that via one command insteed one per one ?

```
netssh wlan add profile filename="C:\wifi_profiles\<profilename>.xml" user=all
```

Its hard to type wifi1.xml hit enter, wifi2.xml hit enter etc.

This dont work:

```
C:\wifi_profiles\*.xml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through them:

```
for %i in (C:\wifi_profiles\*.xml) do netssh wlan add profile filename="%i" user=all
```